# Visual Studio 2010 x64 Compiler on Windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-10

I've installed Visual Studio 2010 Express but I need the x64 compiler toolset. I can not install the compiler toolset with the Windows 7.1 SDK on my Windows 10 machine, it says ".NET Framework 4 is not installed".

How can I get the x64 compilers of Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 8):

For me it worked with the following steps (older Visual Studio version can be downloaded through https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/ (required login))

1. Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express (`en_visual_studio_2010_vc_express_web_installer_x86_516528`)
2. Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (`mu_visual_studio_2010_sp1_web_installer_x86_651694`)
3. Install Microsoft SDK (from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279). Note that when running the installer a warning will appear saying that "some components cannot be installed". Just ignore this (press OK) and continue with the installation using the default settings. Note that the 64-bit C++ compiler is not installed at this point.
4. Install KB2519277 (from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx%3Fid=4422).

Both the 32- and 64-bit Visual Studio 2010 C++ compilers should now be installed.

Note that I'm not sure if all the above steps are actually necessary and if the order is strictly relevant (e.g. it might also work without installing SP1 or installing SP1 later) but this is what worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

I found an installer for VS 2010 Professional on CNet: http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2010-Professional/3000-2212_4-10618634.html It installed the x64 compilers as well.